# Relationship mapping in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

In AGOL, relationship mapping can be done such as shown here,[How to Make a Relationship Map in ArcGIS Online](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/how-to-make-a-relationship-map-in-arcgis-online/)

I have to been trying to find the tool/tools to do the same analysis (with the same symbology and legend) in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for "bivariate colors symbology"

Current help is here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/bivariate-colors.htm